# Make pipenv dependency editable

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Is there a pipenv alternative to npm link?

I want to edit a dependency without having to publish it every time.
Given a project A which depends on project B, I want to clone both and then run pipenv install in project A. Then I want my virtual environment to make a symbolic link to project B such that I can edit it.

I saw that an option `--editable` exists, however I do not want to put this into the Pipfile
since it is just a local development setup and should not be published to my git repo of project A.